# Animación en CSS

Tags: html, css

quisiera saber como hago para que las animaciones sigan un orden consecutivo y no inicien todas al mismo tiempo.

```css
body {
 text-align: center;
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.zoomIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
  animation-name: zoomIn;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <h2 class="header animated zoomIn">Titulo</h2>
 <h5 class="animated zoomIn">Lorem ipsum dolor.</h5>
 <h5 class="animated zoomIn">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h5>
 <h5 class="animated zoomIn">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</h5>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col l4 animated zoomIn">
  <h1>1</h1>
  <h5>Paso Uno</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit urna eget quam facilisis.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="col l4 animated zoomIn">
  <h1>2</h1>
  <h5>Paso Dos</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tortor lectus, ultricies.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="col l4 animated zoomIn">
  <h1>3</h1>
  <h5>Paso Tres</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent rhoncus et leo.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Agradezco su ayuda!

Comment: ¿Cuál es el orden que quieres que tengan?

Comment: Hola! primero el titulo, luego el primer lorem ipsum, luego el segundo lorem ipsum, luego el tercero y así mismo con los tres pasos; uno después del otro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que no todas las animaciones empiecen al mismo tiempo, puedes usar la propiedad [`animation-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) para añadir un poco de retraso a las animaciones. De ese modo puedes darle algo de orden.

En el siguiente ejemplo, basado en tu código, he creado 7 clases: delay1, delay2, ... delay7 que añaden un `animation-delay` de 1, 2, ...7 segundos respectivamente y se lo he asignado a los elementos con .animated para que vayan apareciendo en orden:

```css
body {
 text-align: center;
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.zoomIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
  animation-name: zoomIn;
}

.delay1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.delay2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.delay3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.delay4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.delay5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.delay6 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.delay7 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7s;
  animation-delay: 7s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <h2 class="header animated zoomIn delay1">Titulo</h2>
 <h5 class="animated zoomIn delay2">Lorem ipsum dolor.</h5>
 <h5 class="animated zoomIn delay3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h5>
 <h5 class="animated zoomIn delay4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</h5>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col l4 animated zoomIn delay5">
  <h1>1</h1>
  <h5>Paso Uno</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit urna eget quam facilisis.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="col l4 animated zoomIn delay6">
  <h1>2</h1>
  <h5>Paso Dos</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tortor lectus, ultricies.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="col l4 animated zoomIn delay7">
  <h1>3</h1>
  <h5>Paso Tres</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent rhoncus et leo.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: excelente!! eso era lo que buscaba. Gracias.